# Arguments missing in perforce custom tool

Tags: perl, perforce

I created a custom tool in perforce and passing arguments as follow:

```
generation.pl -c %c -p $c -o $p
```

Now, when I select any changelist and then click on tools in menu bar of Perforce and select the created tool, that tool is getting triggered properly. But if I don't select any changelist and then try to click on the tool, it is not getting triggered.
I know the reason for this that  "-c %c" this parameter wants changelist. But I want that the pl file must be triggered even if any changelist is not selected, so that I can handle that situation and can direct to another code path.

**or is it compulsory that all parameters in the arguments should be passed to trigger the tool?**

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what you requested: running the tool once for each changelist that you provided.  If you want to run it once with the list of changelists, use `%C`

Comment: but when I am not selecting any changelist then the tool is not triggered. So does it mean that it is necessary to select any changelist and then only run that tool?

Comment: Lowercase %c means run once for each changelist.  You gave it 0 changelists, so how many times should it run? https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/custom_tools.html

Comment: I got your point.. But I have 2 requirement- 1. when I m selecting a changelist and then running the tool. 2. when I m not selecting any changelist and then trying to run it. So for second case, I still want to trigger the tool and then handling it in that tool - (like if no changelist is selected take another code path). So is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create another tool entry that does not take a %c argument, and use that tool for the case where you don't have a changelist selected.

Comment: But I don't want to create another tool.. Is there any way to accommodate it in same tool?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to try %C instead of %c and see if that works...